# How to check time overlap in bootstrap date

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, bootstrapping

I want to check shift start time and shift time values overlapped or not. if user enter overlapped values it should prompt error. please advice

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Shift Start:</label>

    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
        <input type='text' name="shift_start" class="form-control"
            id='datetimepicker3' value="{{old('shift_start')}}" /> <span
            class="input-group-addon"> <span
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Shift End:</label>

        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>
            <input type='text' name="shift_end" class="form-control"
                value="{{old('shift_end')}}" /> <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
            </span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my script

```
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
            format: 'HH:mm'
        });
        $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
            format: 'HH:mm'
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a javascript function :

```
function checkTime()
{
var start = $('#datetimepicker3').val();
var end   = $('#datetimepicker5').val();

var tabStart = start.split(':');
var tabEnd   = end.split(':');

var dateStart = new Date();
dateStart.setHours(parseInt(tabStart[0]));
dateStart.setMinutes(parseInt(tabStart[1]));

var dateEnd   = new Date();
dateEnd.setHours(parseInt(tabEnd[0]));
dateEnd.setMinutes(parseInt(tabEnd[1]));

if(dateStart < dateEnd)
{
     alert('ok');
}
else
{
     alert('ko');
}
```

}

Then in you datetimepicker :

```
 $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
        format: 'HH:mm',
        onSelect: function(){
            checkTime();
        }
    });
    $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
        format: 'HH:mm',
        onSelect: function(){
            checkTime();
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: dateStart->setHours(parseInt(tabStart[0]));
        dateStart->setMinutes(parseInt(tabStart[1]));dateStart->setHours(parseInt(tabStart[0]));
        dateStart->setMinutes(parseInt(tabStart[1])); im getting error on these lines. pls advice

Comment: Expression statement is not assignement or call

Comment: My Bad, its not dateStart->setHours but obviously dateStart.setHours. I was writting PHP style and not JS one.